# How to serialize object to xml and compress in memory

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, gzipstream

In my application I need serialize large object to xml string. But then serialized throw System.OutOfMemory exception. How can I serialized object without exception and with compression?

```
public static string GenerateXMLData<T>(T data)
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                binaryFormatter.Serialize(gZipStream, data);
            }
            bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
    }
```

Comment: [BinaryFormatter vs. Manual Serializing](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/311944/BinaryFormatter-or-Manual-serializing) might be useful.

Comment: Why do you have a BinaryFormatter.Serialize() and expect to get Xml ? You need XmlSerializer

Answer (score 0):

there is a lot of good answeers here on stackoverflow that can be accesed through a quick Google searche here is one i found

[Serialize an object to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123590/serialize-an-object-to-xml)

and another that i had to use some time back

[How to make a serializable class that contains an instance of one class from a set of classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326832/how-to-make-a-serializable-class-that-contains-an-instance-of-one-class-from-a-s)

hope it helps mate :)

Comment: LoneWolf, all of that answers not for my situation. My object contains billion items and more