# Serializing an XML in c# with type class showing error

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

```
 Public class Test{
   public string name {get;set;}
   }
```

Trying to serialize this class

```
XmlSerializer serlzer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
```

is showing error as 
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007B)
  + System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(int, System.IntPtr)
  + Microsoft.Win32.Fusion.ReadCache(System.Collections.ArrayList, string, uint)
  + System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.EnumerateCache(System.Reflection.AssemblyName)
  + System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.LoadWithPartialNameInternal(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.Security.Policy.Evidence, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark)
  + System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadWithPartialName(string, System.Security.Policy.Evidence)
  + System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.LoadGeneratedAssembly(System.Type, string, out System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerImplementation)
  + System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(System.Type, string)
  + System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(System.Type)

Done all these in C# interactive in visual studio 2015 in .NET 4.6.1 environment

Comment: And you get a runtime Exception, but no Error with compilation?

Comment: do a simple google search on `C# serialize a Class`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326832/how-to-make-a-serializable-class-that-contains-an-instance-of-one-class-from-a-s

Comment: It was an issue in Roslyn compiler. Just now Found.

Answer (score 0):

**the issue is that generated assembly name for script assemblies contains an invalid character for the file system (#), and when the serializer attempts to load a serialization assembly, it fails.**

try to reinstall the assembly again and see if that works, it happens sometimes that the assembly contains invalid characters.