# C# XmlSerialization Properties Class for an Array contains different elements

Tags: c#, xml, properties, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I am currently working on a WebService and struck at how to define properties class for the below use-case:

```
<Parent>
<Type1>int</Type1>
<Type2>string</Type2>
<Type3>Object</Type3>
<Type3>Object</Type3>
<Type3>Object</Type3>
<Type3>Object</Type3>
</Parent>
```

My code looks like this:

```
[XmlRoot]
class Parent
{
   [XmlElement]
   public int Type1 {get; set;}

   [XmlElement]
   public string Type2 {get; set;}

   [XmlArray]
   public List<Type3ListItem> Type3 {get; set;}
}

public class Type3ListItem
{
   public string ABC {get; set;}
   public string DEF {get; set;}
}
```

And I would like to Deserialize using System.Xml.Serialization, please advise on how to proceed with this use-case. Also advise if using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary; is better than System.Xml.Serialization for better performance to consume XML of size 50MB(approx).

Comment: Have you tried to put  [XmlInclude(typeof(Type3ListItem))] above Parent Class?

Comment: @JawadZeb Thank you for quick reply, no I haven't tried that. I will give it a try.

Comment: Yes dear you can follow this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326832/how-to-make-a-serializable-class-that-contains-an-instance-of-one-class-from-a-s

Comment: Because you also have a list of Type3ListItem In the parent. so the link I pasted is the same that you want to achieve :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326832/how-to-make-a-serializable-class-that-contains-an-instance-of-one-class-from-a-s

Comment: Are you looking for [XML Serialization - Disable rendering root element of array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2006482/3744182)?  If so the answer there explains you just need to apply `[XmlElement("Type3")]` to `Type3` in place of `[XmlArray]`.